# Can Json.NET deserialize a flattened JSON string with dot notation?

Tags: serialization, syntax, json.net

I have a flattened JSON:

```
{
    "CaseName" : "John Doe v. State",
    "CaseDate" : "<some date>",
    "Client.FirstName" : "John",
    "Client.LastName" : "Doe",
    "Client.Email" : "johndoe@gmail.com"
    etc...
}
```

I want to deserialize it back to this entity:

```
public class Case()
{
    public string CaseName { get; set; }
    public string CaseDate { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

where `Client.FirstName`, `Client.LastName`, and `Client.Email` are properties in the `Client` object. Using Json.NET, is there any way to get it to parse the dot notation and deserialize this entity correctly? Currently, using the default settings, it tells me that `Client.FirstName` is not a property in type `Case`.

Comment: I simplified it to make it more readable, but I modified it so it's proper JSON now.

Comment: to expand on ChaosPandion's comment - the standard way represent that nested data (the client) in Json would be more like { "CaseName" : "John Doe v. State", "CaseDate" : "<some date>", "Client" { "FirstName" : "John",  "LastName" : "Doe" }} If its possible to change the outputted Json instead that would be much quicker than @CasperOne's sln. Depends if you have control of the serialisation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.  You would derive a class from [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) and override the [`CanConvert`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) method to indicae that you can convert the `Client` type.

Then, you would override the [`ReadJson`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) and [`WriteJson`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) methods to read and write the fields of the JSON literal.

For a JSON literal like this, it's more than likely you will need to create a `JsonConverter` for the `Case` type, as you will need to cache all the properties of the `Client` object during serialization until you have enough information to actually create the `Client` instance.

Then, you would call the `Add` method on the [`JsonConverterCollection`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterCollection.htm) instance exposed by the [`Converters` property](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Converters.htm) on the [`JsonSerializer`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) instance you are using to perform your serialization/deserialization.

Note that if you need to do this for a number of different classes that might be represented in this manner, then you can write *one* `JsonConverter` implementation, and have it scan for an attribute on the property.  If the property has the attribute and exposes another object with properties, it would expect to read/write the dot-notation.

It should be noted that while you are using the dot-notation for the identifier, it's very uncommon to do so.  If possible, on the side that is constructing the JSON literal, it should be doing it in this manner:

```
{ 
    CaseName: "John Doe v. State", 
    CaseDate: "<some date>", 
    Client: 
    {
        FirstName: "John", 
        LastName: "Doe", 
        Email: "johndoe@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

But that's assuming that you have control over that end.  If you don't, then there's not much you can do.

If you do have control, then constructing your JSON literals in that manner would negate the need for a custom `JsonConverter` implementation.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to convert it correctly on the sender's side (ExtJS), but I'm not sure if that's possible yet. The solution you provided is workable, but too much work given the number of entities and complexity of my object graph. I was hoping for a simple flag or a more generic JsonConverter that would apply for all dot notation properties.

Comment: @Daniel T.: Unfortunately, the JSON is non-standard, which is why Json.NET has problems with it.  However, I've added a paragraph to the answer to indicate how you can write *one* JsonConverter implementation, combined with an attribute to tell it to read/write dot-notation when expected.

Answer (score 0):

simple code

```cs
 public class SimpleDotJsonPropertyConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public const string SplitChar = ".";

        private readonly NamingStrategy _namingStrategy;

        public SimpleDotJsonPropertyConverter() : this(new DefaultNamingStrategy())
        {

        }

        public SimpleDotJsonPropertyConverter(Type namingStrategyType) : this(namingStrategyType.CreateInstance() as NamingStrategy)
        {

        }

        public SimpleDotJsonPropertyConverter(NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
        {
            _namingStrategy = namingStrategy;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                writer.WriteRaw("{}");
                return;
            }
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            var type = value.GetType();
            var props = type.GetPublicProperties();
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                if (p.PropertyType.IsValueType || p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(_namingStrategy.GetPropertyName(p.Name, false));
                    writer.WriteValue(p.GetValue(value));
                }
                else
                {
                    var parentName = p.Name;
                    var subProps = p.PropertyType.GetPublicProperties();
                    var memberValue = p.GetValue(value);
                    foreach (var sp in subProps)
                    {
                        writer.WritePropertyName(_namingStrategy.GetPropertyName(parentName, false) + SplitChar + _namingStrategy.GetPropertyName(sp.Name, false));
                        writer.WriteValue(sp.GetValue(memberValue));
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            var result = objectType.CreateInstance();
            foreach (var item in jsonObject)
            {
                if (item.Key.IsNullOrEmpty()) continue;
                var nameArrays = item.Key.Split(SplitChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (nameArrays.Length <= 1)
                {
                    var p = objectType.GetProperty(item.Key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (p != null)
                    {
                        if (item.Value == null)
                            p.SetValue(result, objectType.GetDefaultValue());
                        else
                            p.SetValue(result, item.Value.ToObject(p.PropertyType));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var name = nameArrays[0];
                    var subName = nameArrays[1];
                    var p = objectType.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (p == null) continue;
                    var subProp = p.PropertyType.GetProperty(subName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (subProp == null) continue;
                    if (!subProp.PropertyType.IsValueType && subProp.PropertyType != typeof(string)) throw new NotSupportedException("Nested complex objects are not supported ");
                    var member = p.GetValue(result);
                    if (member == null)
                    {
                        member = p.PropertyType.CreateInstance();
                        p.SetValue(result, member);
                    }

                    if (item.Value == null)
                        subProp.SetValue(member, objectType.GetDefaultValue());
                    else
                        subProp.SetValue(member, item.Value.ToObject(subProp.PropertyType));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType.IsClass;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Although **only half the problem** (i.e. *not helping with the fact your object has been flattened*)

You can deal with **dot notation** in a very **quick and dirty** way with a simple

```
MyTargetClass retVal 
= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTargetClass>(jsonAsString.Replace(".", "_"));
```

In combo with appropriate "_" property names on the MyTargetClass e.g.

```
public class MyTargetClass
{
    public string CaseName {get; set;}
    public DateTime CaseDate {get; set;}
    public string Client_FirstName {get; set;}

    //Other Properties
}
```

Comment: That requires a completely new object to deserialize into.

Comment: @LarryBud can you expand on what exactly you mean by "a completely new object"?  Also did you notice the ***quick and dirty*** and my comment on the OP. I clearly don't think this is optimal, but It ***does answer the question and does not misrepresent said answer as something other than a quick and dirty fix***.

Comment: The OP was saying they can't or probably cannot modified the code producing the JSON, they have to work with it as is. So what's the problem changing a few property names on a single class to get the job done?

Comment: when you say "object" do you mean "class"? With most .net applications adding a single new class is not exactly the worst thing ever is it?