# Rendering JSON input with obj.property and obj.property[index] using JsonPropertyName()

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I am using `System.Text.Json.Serialization` with `JsonPropertyName("obj.property")` in a .NET Core 3.1 based web api project to deserialize JSON input to a C# POCO object. The input contains few attributes with dots, i.e.,

```json
"id": "B1346",
"businessType": "RENTAL",
"company.city": "LUND",
"company.zipcode": "99999",
"company.email": "support@samplecompany.com",
"user.email[0]": "support2@samplecompany.com",
"user.name[0]": "Tom",
"user.email[1]": "support3@samplecompany.com",
"user.name[1]": "Harry",
```

I have created following POCO object:

```cs
public class Form
{
  public string Id { get; set;}
  public string BusinessType { get; set;}
  [JsonPropertyName("company.city")]
  public string CompanyCity { get; set;}
  [JsonPropertyName("company.zipcode")]
  public string CompanyZipcode { get; set;}
  [JsonPropertyName("company.email")]
  public string CompanyEmail { get; set;}
  [JsonPropertyName("user.email")]
  public List<string> UserEmail { get; set;}
  [JsonPropertyName("user.name")]
  public List<string> UserName { get; set;}
}
```

So far it has worked for simple attributes with dot, e.g., `company.city`, but not for array elements, e.g., `users.name[0]`

```cs
public async Task PostApplication(Form form)
{ ... }
```

Quick watch (during debug) shows the successful deserialization of all properties for the parameter "form" except arrays:

[image: quickwatch]

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2391008/8104777

Comment: If you want to handle this "generically" you will need to write [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you have only [0] and [1] try this classes

```
public class Root
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string businessType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("company.city")]
        public string CompanyCity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("company.zipcode")]
        public string CompanyZipcode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("company.email")]
        public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("user.email[0]")]
        public string UserFirsEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("user.name[0]")]
        public string UserFirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("user.email[1]")]
        public string UserSecondEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("user.name[1]")]
        public string UserSecondName { get; set; }
    }
```

if you have arrays with more than 2 elements you need much more complicated code. But I can't see anything else in your post.

```
var jD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
var data = new Data {
        Id=jD.id,
        BusinessType=jD.businessType,
        Company = new Company { City = jD.CompanyCity, Email = jD.CompanyEmail },
        User = new User {Name=jD.UserName0, Email=jD.UserEmail0, SecondName=jD.UserName1, SecondEmail=jD.UserEmail1}
    }
```

classes

```
public class Data
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string BusinessType { get; set; }

    public Company Company {get;set;}
    public User User {get;set;}
}
public class Company
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondEmail { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have only 2 elements and I have no control on the receiving data (JSON). Thank you @Serge ... although it looks weird, but your first suggestion worked!

Comment: @Imtiaz You are very welcome. I always prefer the simpliest way . It is easy to mantain and  usually the most reliable too.

Answer (score 0):

The items in the list need to be JSON list format, it should look like this to be deserialized as a string list :

```
{
  "id": "B1346",
  "businessType": "RENTAL",
  "company.city": "LUND",
  "company.zipcode": "99999",
  "company.email": "support@samplecompany.com",
  "user.email": ["support2@samplecompany.com", "support3@samplecompany.com"]
  "user.name": ["Tom","Harry]
}
```